# What do you call the wooden structure or the site where a boat docks?

Tags: word-request

[image]

[image]

The above two screenshots are taken from a FPS game. I thought we could call the wooden structure a jetty, but I'm not sure it's the right word for it. Any other words for this meaning?

Does the site qualify as a harbor or a dock?

Comment: Are the buildings in the second picture dwellings? Did you look up these words in a good dictionary? Harbor, dock, wharf, jetty..

Comment: @TRomano Those loose definitions don't help much. I have a vocabulary of over 10000. I know what I need to know.

Comment: What loose definitions?  You haven't cited a single one. What is your idea of a good dictionary?

Comment: @TRomano Note that I was requesting a word that could match the screenshots. It's a very specific question. I didn't ask how a jetty or a harbor looked like.

Comment: You apparently don't even realize what you're saying. You asked "Does the site qualify as a harbor or a dock?"

Comment: @TRomano I think ssav pretty much answered my question; it's not that complicated. Anyway, not all my questions could meet your standards, but this one at least doesn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: Of course it does. If I succeed in my secret mission, you won't confuse this little wooden dock  with a "harbor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the first one a jetty, and the second a boat house.

Since boats can dock there, either could be called a dock, although I would normally use 'dock' to refer to the place where cargo ships load and unload their cargo.

Neither is a harbour, because a harbour is a place where boats are stored to protect them from stormy weather.

Comment: Thx! I like your explanation without going into technical details. Would you call either a berth or a wharf instead?

Comment: You could say wharf, as that means pretty much the same thing as jetty.  Not berth though, as that is a boat's assigned place at a wharf or dock, which doesn't really apply to small places like the ones in the pictures.